# HTML_TO_DOC() looping table from database

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I was been in charge for a system that still using HTML_TO_DOC() with PHP.
My question is, i want to display all data from database using table.

Here is my coding example:

```
   $htmlContent=$html_2.'
<table width=100% border=1 cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
      <th width="5" bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">BIL</th>
      <th bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">NAMA</th>
      <th width="15" bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">JAWATAN</th>
      <th width="10" bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">TELEFON</th>
      <th width="10" bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">EMEL</th>
   </tr>
   ';
   $i=0;
   foreach($penyelaras as $plaras){
   $htmlContent2=$html_2.'
   <tr>
      <td width="5" class="style8" valign="top">'.$i.'</td>
      <td align="left" class="style10" valign="top">'.$plaras->nama.'</td>
      <td width="15" class="style10" valign="top">'.$plaras->nama_jawatan.'</td>
      <td width="10" class="style10" 
         valign="top">PEJ:'.$plaras->tel_no_p.'<br>HP:'.$plaras->tel_no_hp.'</td>
      <td width="10" class="style8" valign="top">'.$plaras->emel.'</td>
   </tr>
   ';
   $i++;
   }
   $htmlContent=$html_3.'
</table>
';
$soalan=$htmlContent.$htmlContent2;
$htmltodoc->createDoc($soalan,"cetakan",true);
```

The result only shows 1 row only just like image (resulterror) below. Please help if i got mistake in my looping statement.

resulterror

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$head ='<table width=100% border=1 cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th width="5" bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">BIL</th>
                    <th bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">NAMA</th>
                    <th width="15" bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">JAWATAN</th>
                    <th width="10" bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">TELEFON</th>
                    <th width="10" bgcolor="#999999" class="style8">EMEL</th>
                </tr>';
            $i=0;
            $Content2 = "";
            foreach($penyelaras as $plaras){
            $Content2 .= '<tr>
                <td width="5" class="style8" valign="top">'.$i.'</td>
                <td align="left" class="style10" valign="top">'.$plaras->nama.'</td>
                <td width="15" class="style10" valign="top">'.$plaras->nama_jawatan.'</td>
                <td width="10" class="style10" 
                   valign="top">PEJ:'.$plaras->tel_no_p.'<br>HP:'.$plaras->tel_no_hp.'</td>
                <td width="10" class="style8" valign="top">'.$plaras->emel.'</td>
            </tr>';
            $i++;
            }


$soalan=$head.$Content2.'</table>';
$htmltodoc->createDoc($soalan,"cetakan",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this:

```
$htmlContent2=$html_2;
foreach($penyelaras as $plaras){
'<tr>
    <td width="5" class="style8" valign="top">'.$i.'</td>
    <td align="left" class="style10" valign="top">'.$plaras->nama.'</td>
    <td width="15" class="style10" valign="top">'.$plaras->nama_jawatan.'</td>
    <td width="10" class="style10" 
       valign="top">PEJ:'.$plaras->tel_no_p.'<br>HP:'.$plaras->tel_no_hp.'</td>
    <td width="10" class="style8" valign="top">'.$plaras->emel.'</td>
</tr>'
$i++;
};
```

Comment: I try using this code but i got error at foreach statement. Btw, thanks Simone